# Prometheus moniter Docker Swarm (Load balanced) endpoint Inbox x

Tags: spring-boot, monitoring, docker-swarm, prometheus

I was able to setup Prometheus and Grafana to monitor one of my Springboot API. That is working fine as expected when we have a single instance/replica in given target endpoint.

However in our enterprise environment we are running Springboot app as a Docker Swarm service. A docker service has a single endpoint,  but there are multiple instances/replicas of applications under a single service.
How do we configure prometheus to monitor all replicas since  they have only one endpoint.

If I generalize, how does Prometheus monitor all instances of a load balanced endpoint.

```
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'prometheus'

    metrics_path: '/prometheus'

    static_configs:
      - targets: ['api.springboot.myhost.com:8080']
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure Prometheus to scrape all instances, never scrape through a load balancer for a replicated job.

For Swarm doesn't have API to allow you to discover its services over the network yet, so the best approach is to use something like [Consul](https://github.com/hashicorp/consul)+[Registrar](https://github.com/gliderlabs/registrator).